# First common element across multiple arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to find the first common element across a group of arrays.  The number of arrays may vary, but they are always in sequential order (small->large).  My arrays are all properties of myObj.

This is what I have so far:

```
function compare(myObj,v,j) {
  if (myObj[j].indexOf(v)>-1) return true;
  else return false;
}

function leastCommon ([1,5]) {
  var myObj = { //This is filled by code, but the finished result looks like this
    1: [1, 2,...,60,...10k]
    2: [2, 4,...,60,...20k]
    3: [3, 6,...,60,...30k]
    4: [4, 8,...,60,...40k]
    5: [5,10,...,60,...50k]
  };
  var key = [1,2,3,4,5]; //also filled by code
  var lcm = myObj[key[key.length-1]].forEach(function(v) { //Iterate through last/largest multiple array
  var j=key[key.length-2];
  while (j>=0) {
    if (compare(myObj,v,j)) {  //check to see if it is in the next lower array, if yes, check the next one.
      j--;
    }
    if (j>0 && (compare(myObj,v,j+1))===true) return v;  //before the loop exits, return the match
   }  
 });
return lcm;
}
```

I'm not sure what is wrong, but it is returning undefined.

Note:  yes, I know a forEach returns undefined, and I tried modifying my code, and I get a "potential infinite loop" error from my editor. Modified code looks like this:

```
function leastCommon ([1,5]) {
  var myObj = { //This is filled by code, but the finished result looks like this
    1: [1, 2,...,60,...10k]
    2: [2, 4,...,60,...20k]
    3: [3, 6,...,60,...30k]
    4: [4, 8,...,60,...40k]
    5: [5,10,...,60,...50k]
  };
  var key = [1,2,3,4,5]; //also filled by code
  var lcm = 0;
  myObj[key[key.length-1]].forEach(function(v) { //Iterate through last/largest multiple array
    var j=key[key.length-2];
    while (j>=0) {
      if (compare(myObj,v,j)) {  //check to see if it is in the next lower array, if yes, check the next one.
        j--;
      }
      if (j>0 && (compare(myObj,v,j+1))===true) lcm = v;  //before the loop exits, set lcm = v
    }  
  });
return lcm;
}
```

Comment: please add some examples and the wanted result.

Comment: @Nina Scholz   I've been tasked with finding the least common multiple of two numbers, and all the numbers in between.  So I decided that I should create an array of multiples for each number, then find the first multiple in common across all arrays.       Example:  input = 1-5; result should equal 60.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not use forEach since there is no way to exit from the method when you find the first match/failure. You would need to keep looping. Instead you should look into a regular for loop with every and indexOf. This code also assumes that the array is sorted so smallest number comes first. If not, a simple sort() with a clone of the array can solve that.

```js
//pass in arrays, assumes array is sorted
function getFirstCommon (arrs) {
  //Loop over the elements in the first array
  for (var i=0; i<arrs[0].length; i++) {
    //get the value for the current index
    var val = arrs[0][i];
    //make sure every array has the value
    //if every does not find it, it returns false
    var test = arrs.every( function (arr) {
      //check the array to see if it has the element
      return arr.indexOf(val)!==-1;  
    });
    //If we find it, than return the current value
    if (test) {
      return val;
    }   
  }
  //if nothing was found, return null
  return null; 
}

//test numbers
var nums = [
   [1,2,3,4,5,6],
   [2,3,4,5,6],
   [3,4,5,6],
   [4,5,6,7,8,9],
   [6,7,8,9]
];
  
console.log(getFirstCommon(nums));  //6
  
var nums2 = [
   [1,2,3,4,5,6],
   [2,3,4,5,6],
   [3,4,5,6],
   [4,5,6,7,8,9],
   [5,7,8,9]
];
  
console.log(getFirstCommon(nums2));  //5

var nums3 = [
   [1,2,3,4,5,6],
   [7,8,9,10,11,12],
   [7,8,9,10,11,12]
];
  
console.log(getFirstCommon(nums3));  //null
```

The code could be improved where it does not check itself

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you do have an infinite loop. If first `compare()` fails, you never decrease `j`, and keep checking the same number.

Second: you `key` array never decreases, so you always compare two last arrays.

Comment: OK, I see the infinite loop. For some reason, I thought it would break the loop on false, and go to the next number.  I will rework.